# ошибка eoferror: eof when reading a line. в чем проблема

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
lst = []

while True:
    a = input()
    if a == '':
        break
    else:
        a = int(a)
        lst.append(a)

if len(lst) == 0:
    print(-1)
else:
    print(sum(lst) / len(lst))
```

ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/temp/executing/solution.py", line 4, in <module>
    a = int(input())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
make: *** [run] Error 1
```

Comment: это какая-то проверяющая система? и у вас в коде нет строки `a = int(input())`, на которую ругается трейс

Comment: @Jack_oS скорее всего - видимо вывод не соответствует шаблону, который ожидается

Comment: когда я его запускаю в среде на пк все работает, все нужные ответы дает, а при передаче этого кода на сайт для проверки теста он выдает эту ошибку

Comment: покажите адрес, куда передаете код?

Comment: условия задачи не плохо бы

Comment: или не тот файл передаете)